# How to untangle a bad mysql user configuration?

Tags: mysql

**Situation**

I have a mysql server, with a messy user configuration : there are two different entries having the same login `admn`.

```
mysql> select user,host,grant_priv from mysql.user where user="admn";
+------+---------------------------+------------+
| user | host                      | grant_priv |
+------+---------------------------+------------+
| admn | 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0 | N          |
| admn | 192.168.0.21              | Y          |
+------+---------------------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Notice how only the second one (host `192.168.0.21`) has the "grant" privilege.

For completeness, here is as view of the two users' privileges :

```
mysql> show grants for 'admn'@'192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0';
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for admn@192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0                                                      |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admn'@'192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '---' |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show grants for 'admn'@'192.168.0.21';
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for admn@192.168.0.21                                                                        |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admn'@'192.168.0.21' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '---' WITH GRANT OPTION |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The mysql server's version is :

```
mysql> select version();
+-----------------------+
| version()             |
+-----------------------+
| 5.1.63-0+squeeze1-log |
+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Problem**

When I log in from the `192.168.0.21` machine using `adm`'s credentials, I get identified as `'admn'@'192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0'` :

```
mysql> select user(), current_user();
+-------------------+--------------------------------+
| user()            | current_user()                 |
+-------------------+--------------------------------+
| admn@192.168.0.21 | admn@192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0 |
+-------------------+--------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

and since this account doesn't have the "grant" privilege, I'm stuck regarding privilege administration.

**Question**

How can I access `'admn'@'192.168.0.21'` acount ?

Comment: 192.168.0.0 - that is your router, correct?

Comment: You might try changing the routers IP address.. to say 192.168.0.100 - then use the 192.168.0.21 address and see if that helps. Good question by the way.

Comment: Then of course, if that works... the first thing you do is straighten those user settings... then naturally you can change the router settings back.

Comment: If I am just talking rubbish, someone just let me know. cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to change your account that has a subnet so that it uses a wildcard, i.e. change `192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0` to `192.168.0.%`.

The reason for this is that MySQL chooses users preferentially according to how specific their host is, and that specificity is the same for `192.168.0.21` and `192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0`, but the wildcard version (which means the same thing as the subnetted version!) has a lower specificity.

See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connection-access.html):

> The specificity of a literal IP address is not affected by whether it has a netmask, so 192.168.1.13 and 192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0 are considered equally specific... The pattern '%' means “any host” and is least specific.

Comment: Yes, good solution, but OP's problem seems to be that they can't even get into an account that permits changing permissions or user setting at all... or maybe I am wrong.. +1 regardless.

Comment: His account has write privileges on the `mysql` database, so he can fix this problem even if he only has access to the `.21` account by, for example, updating the `mysql.user` table and then issuing a `FLUSH PRIVILEGES`.

Comment: OK. Perhaps that could be part of the answer as well by the way. All the best.

Comment: @JeremySmyth : hadn't seen that line in the manual. Thanks, it solved my problem. I find it awkward that a user without "GRANT" privilege can modify the credentials of another account, but it definitely helped here.